# How to parse and translate 必须要有?

Tags: meaning

Edit: typo, wrote '必需‘ instead of '必须’.

Is '必须要有‘ 2 or 3 words? What does it mean? It seems to say 'must have (必需） must （要） have （有）

人必需要有自己的追求，

In English we use 'needs must', for example, often heard in 'Needs must when the devil drives', although it is somewhat old-fashioned, but not archaic. It is still heard.

Is ’必需要有‘ 'needs must'?

人必需要有自己的追求， 'a person needs must have a pursuit'

Cf: Shakespeare's 'All’s Well that Ends Well': The Clown says to the Countess: “My poor body, madam, requires it: I am driven on by the flesh; and he must needs go that the devil drives”.

Answer (score 1):

ABC dictionary defines **要有** as

> V.
>
> need; require

giving the example:

> 开箱子要有钥匙。
>
> Kāi xiāngzi yàoyǒu yàoshi.
>
> One needs the key to open the suitcase.

**必需** you can think of as essential, indispensable or necessary.

---

Your translation:
人必需要有自己的追求， 'a person needs must have a pursuit'

while not *wrong* - could probably be better thought of as **definitely necessary** instead.

Answer (score 1):

There are difference between [必须 and 必需](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22009/what-is-the-difference-between-%E5%BF%85%E9%A1%BB-%E5%BE%97-and-%E9%9C%80%E8%A6%81)

必需要有 = (必需)(要有)= (need)(need to have) is not a meaningful phrase(redundant).

You can either say 必需金錢(need money) or 要有金錢(need to have money) but 必需要有金錢 would mean "need, need to have money"

You can use 必需 and 要有 in sentence like this: "做奶酪**必需**時間, **要有**耐性" (making cheese **need** time, **need to have** patience)

必须 = must/ need to

要有 = need to have

必须要有= "must need to have" [is also structurally redundant, but people often use this phrase instead of 必须有(**must** have) or 须要有 (need to have).]

I think 必须要有 is the combination of 必须有 and 须要有-- they all mean "need to have".

> *Is ’必须要有‘ 'needs must'?*

No, 'needs must' is a proverb that means "sometimes you have to do something you would rather not."

Comment: 如果写： ‘人必须自己的追求，’ 好不好？ ‘ ’必须有须要有‘ 比 ’必须要有‘更长！

Comment: 1. 必须 always followed by a verb phrase, 自己的追求 is a noun phrase, therefore, it should be ‘人必须**要有**自己的追求. 2. Instead of saying ’必须有' **or** '须要有' , people say "必须要有". No one would say "必须有须要有" together (the two phrases mean the same)

Comment: Or you can say 人必须自己追求 (man must pursuit on his own) ; 追求 would be a verb. You then need an object after that

Answer (score 1):

First, 人*必需* 要有自己的追求 is wrong. The correct one should be 人*必须* 要有自己的追求.

必须: must, have to;

要 is a modal word, which connotes 'need', 'want', 'require' and 'demand'.

有：have

In practice, 要 and 必须 have some overlaps in meaning, but if they are put it together(必须要), it conveys a stronger emphasis.

Both 必须要有 and 必须有 mean 'must have'.

必须要有 is a bit stronger than 必须有， and 必须有 is more casual than 必须要有.

人必须要有自己的追求, as a whole, could be translated to "one must have one's own pursuit/dream."