# What is the difference between 需 and 須?

Tags: meaning, difference

I am wondering what the difference between 需 and 須 is. They seem close enough while 需 slightly hints to me that it is an "optional" kind of want, while 須 is a "demanding" want. Is this correct and is there a better way to think of them? Thanks!

Comment: 《易・需》：＂需，須也。＂ lol.............

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between 必须, 得, and 需要?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22009/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%bf%85%e9%a1%bb-%e5%be%97-and-%e9%9c%80%e8%a6%81) .... First let's clarify the definitions of 須 and 需

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question: [What is the difference between 必须, 得, and 需要?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/22009/what-is-the-difference-between-%e5%bf%85%e9%a1%bb-%e5%be%97-and-%e9%9c%80%e8%a6%81) already explained the difference between 需 and 須.

Basically:

需(need) apply to noun. For example: "必需品" (品 is a noun)

須(need to; must) apply to verb. For example: "須知人言可畏" (知 is a verb)

*必需品: necessity; essential thing*

*[人言可畏](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/42340/) criticisms should be feared; gossip is a fearful thing*

Comment: 这样划分并不对。需和须在“需要”这层意思上并没有分别。目前，需多用于客观的需要，须一般带有更强烈的主管需要的语气。“学习高等代数需有线性代数的基础。”“明日须阎先生来这事才能解决。”

Comment: 即便是上述两句，需和须也有调换的可能。

Comment: 需....线性代数的基础 (n); 须....来(v)

Comment: 公司须要有(v)阎先生 - the company need to have Mr. Yan. ; 公司需要阎先生(n) -the company need Mr. Yan